# Is this a scope issue or how function creation issue?

Tags: javascript

I haven't done Javascript in years and I'm trying to get back into it.  I just wanted to create a couple random numbers and add them together.  I also wanted to practice using "getVariable()" to protect manipulation of the original variable while making them accessible to the entire script.  I must be remembering this wrong or I'm doing something really stupid.  I keeping getting a message that getScore1 is undefined.  I tried writing it as function getScore1() and this.getScore1 = function(){}.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

```
function twoRandomScores(){
    var score1 = Math.random(1, 10);
    var score2 = Math.random(1, 10);
    return score1 + score2;
    this.getScore1 = function(){
            return this.score1;
        }
    function getScore2(){
            return this.score2;
        }
}

document.write(getScore1() + '+' + getScore2() + '=' + twoRandomScores());
```

Comment: It is a scope issue.

Comment: Thank you - could you please refresh my memory.  How would I fix this?

Comment: A variable is not a property, you can't access it with `this.`. Also, did you try [write a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)?

Answer (score 2):

The `getScore` functions are defined *inside* your `twoRandomScores()` function so they won't simply be accessible from outside of it. The code as you've written it now doesn't really make sense either because the `getScore()` functions would only have any meaning *after* `twoRandomScores()` was called (and for one particular call of it). Here's one way you could approach this problem:

```
function twoRandomScores(){
    var score1 = Math.random(1, 10);
    var score2 = Math.random(1, 10);
    return {
        score: score1 + score2,
        getScore1: function(){
            return score1;
        },
        getScore2: function(){
            return score2;
        }
    };
}

var scores = twoRandomScores();
console.log(scores.getScore1() + '+' + 
            scores.getScore2() + '=' + 
            scores.score);
```

Then again, having two functions for `getScore1`, `getScore2` doesn't really accomplish anything, so you could just do:

```
function twoRandomScores(){
    var score1 = Math.random(1, 10);
    var score2 = Math.random(1, 10);
    return {
        score: score1 + score2,
        score1: score1,
        score2: score2
    };
}

var scores = twoRandomScores();
console.log(scores.score1 + '+' + scores.score2 + '=' + scores.score);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is the explanation I was looking for.  The point of getScore function within a function is to access a private variable without subjecting it to changes.  I remember the point I just forget the code exactly.  I'll have to look that part up somewhere.  Thank you for clarifying the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that your code is correct? Before assigning getScore1, you are returning out of the function, so the assignment to getScore1 and getScore2 never occurs. Hence the undefined error...

Comment: `getScore2` is hoisted but `getScore1` isn't. The main issue is about scope I'd say, but that's a good point.

Comment: Thanks - Good point.  I tried moving it, but I still get "Uncaught ReferenceError: getScore1 is not defined" in the console.

Comment: You'd probably need to move the this.getScore1 = function ()... etc parts outside of the twoRandomScores() function, but then that leaves a need to define 'var score1' outside of the twoRandomScores() function as well... Or follow the other provided answers :p

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up a regular function with the type of function used to create an object. This is how it might work if you wanted to make an object ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv14gooa/))

```
function RandomScore() {
   var score1 = Math.random() * 10,
       score2 = Math.random() * 10;

   // make functions which are properties of the new object
   this.sum = function() {   
       return score1 + score2;
   }
   this.getScore1 = function() {
       return score1;
   }
   this.getScore2 = function() {
       return score2;
   }
}
var randomScore = new RandomScore();
console.log(randomScore.getScore1() + '+' + randomScore.getScore2() + '=' + randomScore.sum());
```

The following would also work without making an object, although it would be rather unusual in practice ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgne9nb5/)):

```
var getScore1, getScore2, sum;   // define variables with global scope
function randomScore() {
    var score1 = Math.random() * 10,
        score2 = Math.random() * 10;
    getScore1 = function() {
        return score1;
    }
    getScore2 = function() {
        return score2;
    }
    return score1 + score2;
}

// we need to run the function once before 
// getScore1 and getScore2 will have any functions assigned to them
sum = randomScore();

// now we can access getScore1 and getScore2 outside of our randomScore function
console.log(getScore1() + '+' + getScore2() + '=' + sum);
```